# Running child coroutines in parallel with cancellation

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

Let's say I have following code:

```
interface Process {
    suspend fun run()
}

class ParallelProcess(initialChildren: List<Process>): Process {
    
    val children = mutableListOf(initialChildren)
    
    override suspend fun run() {
        if(!isActive()) throw IllegalStateException()
        
        // Run all the children here and wait for them
        // including the one that may have been added 
        // while this is running.
        
        markInactive()
    }
    
    fun addChild(child: Process) {
        // Add the child and start running it.
    }
    
    fun cancel() {
        // Cancel all the children and this process as well.
    }
}
```

So the idea is the class `ParalleProcess` will run all the child processes in parallel
and more children can be added while it is still running.

The child process are independent and does not affect each other so if one fails the others and parent are not effected. I think here `SuprevisorJob` may fit for use but I am not sure how to use in this case.

Cancelling the parent process should cancel all the children as well.

What is the best way achieve the above functionality.

Comment: You may use a concurrent list, but you may run into a race condition between calling `addChild` and `cancel`. It may result in a job added but never started or cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

```
class DefaultProcess(private val delay: Long) : Process {
    override suspend fun run() {
        delay(delay)
        log("DefaultProcess($delay) done.")
    }
}

private fun CoroutineScope.runProcesses(parallelProcess: ParallelProcess) = launch {
    parallelProcess.run()
}

private fun log(msg: String) = println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] $msg")

class ParallelProcess(private val initialChildren: List<Process>) : Process {
    private var jobs = mutableListOf<Job>()
    private val children = MutableSharedFlow<Process>(
        extraBufferCapacity = 1,
        onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST
    )

    override suspend fun run() {
        val time = measureTimeMillis {
            coroutineScope {
                initialChildren.forEach { child ->
                    jobs.add(launch { child.run() })
                }

                val flowJob = children
                    .onEach { child ->
                        log("added: DefaultProcess")
                        jobs.add(launch { child.run() })
                    }
                    .launchIn(this)

                while (jobs.isActive) delay(10) // Keep checking if jobs are done
                flowJob.cancel() // When done cancel the flowJob so that "run" can finally return
            }
        }
        log("Total running time: $time ms.")
    }

    fun addChild(child: Process): Boolean {
        return if (jobs.isActive) children.tryEmit(child) else false
    }

    fun cancel() {
        jobs.forEach { job -> job.cancel() }
    }

    private val List<Job>.isActive: Boolean
        get() = any { job -> job.isActive }
}
```

An example (using runBlocking and job.join() to block the main thread until its done, so that output can be seen, **do not block the main thread with runBlocking in production!!!**):

```
val processes = listOf(
        DefaultProcess(100),
        DefaultProcess(50),
        DefaultProcess(300),
        DefaultProcess(500)
    )

runBlocking {
    val scope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.IO)
    val parallelProcess = ParallelProcess(processes)
    val job = scope.runProcesses(parallelProcess)

    /*// Comment out to check that adding new jobs works
    delay(300)

    // It will be added, but immediately dropped, because we're adding a new value down below, before this
    // one is processed, and we have a strategy onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST
    var added = parallelProcess.addChild(DefaultProcess(300))
    log("added1: $added")

    // This one will be added
    added = parallelProcess.addChild(DefaultProcess(400))
    log("added2: $added")

    delay(600) // run already done, child won't be added
    added = parallelProcess.addChild(DefaultProcess(200))
    log("added3: $added")*/

    /*// Comment out to check that cancel also works
    // Delayed for 350, so the first three jobs are done, but if want to start adding without delaying, you need
    to delay for at least 1ms, to give some time to jobs to turn its state into active, otherwise isActive will
    return false and child will not be added.
    delay(350)
    val added = parallelProcess.addChild(DefaultProcess(4000))
    log("added: $added")
    delay(2000)
    parallelProcess.cancel() // Compare times with and without cancelling*/
    job.join()
}
```

You won't be able to add children concurrently (only the last child will be added), if you want not to lose any values, make `addChild` suspend and instead of `tryEmit` use `emit` and make `newChildren = MutableSharedFlow()` without any parameters provided (default values). This will still add children sequentially but it will suspend if new child is being added, before the last one is added to the jobs. For concurrency you'd have to use channels, where `addChild` would produce values and inside `run` you'd have multiple (depending on the number of concurrent consumers you want to have) coroutines consuming those values. But again, since all of these consumers would mute `jobs`, you'd have to use something to synchronize it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
class ParallelProcess(initialChildren: List<Process>): Process {
    
    val children = initialChildren.toMutableList()
    val parentScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob())
    
    override suspend fun run(){ 
        parentScope.launch {
            if(!isActive) throw IllegalStateException()

            // Run all the children here and wait for them
            // including the one that may have been added 
            // while this is running.
            children.map { launch { it.run() } }.joinAll()
            //  markInactive()
        }
    }
    
    fun addChild(child: Process) {
        // Add the child and start running it.
        children += child
        // either wait for all children to finish or call cancel()
        // Or you can make sure to run only processes that are not started
        parentScope.launch {
            run()
        }
    }
    
    fun cancel() {
        // Cancel all the children and this process as well.
        parentScope.cancel()
    }
}
```

Though adding a child creates another concurrency question, that you should address, based on the behaviour you want. I've tried to add some comments to discuss some of the possibilities

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want that `run()` being suspending does not return until all the children are done. In your version will `run()` will return immediately.

Comment: Also the `addChild()` must not wait and return immediately after adding and launching the child. The `run()` must wait for this newly added child.